# Vaadin upload works on localhost, but fails on server

Tags: upload, glassfish, vaadin, ioexception, multipart

The goal was to use the Vaadin [upload-component](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/components.upload.html) to upload files. On localhost it just works fine while on the server I get the error message below.

I am running the application on a Glassfish 3.1.2 (build 23) and use Vaadin 7.4.1. Also have tried other Glassfish versions except Glassfish 4, as I have a dependency that is not yet ready for Glassfish 4.

Things tried or checked:

- Size-limit: Not defined, files used ranged from 10kb to 500kb.
- JVM version: Neither using the exact same version (1.7.0_52), nor playing with different patch-levels or java versions (1.8) changed the situation.
- Possible port restrictions: Used more restricted and completely open security groups.
- Provider: Tried Amazon AWS and DigitalOcean.
- Fresh system: Set up a fresh system with just minimal installations to run the application.
- Hardware resources: Whilst Amazon AWS (micro) is quite limited, the instance of DigitalOcean runs with 2 CPUs and 4GB ram.
- Glassfish: Used several 3.x versions.
- Upload component: Used the vaadin provided [upload component](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/components.upload.html) and the addon [easy uploads](http://vaadin.com/directory#addon/easyuploads).

Things not checked:

- OS: My dev system is running Windows 8.1 while the server is linux based.
- Glassfish 4.x: As my jenkins deploy plugin is not yet ready for Glassfish 4.x I did not try that yet.
- Vaadin: Did not yet downgrade Vaadin.

The code of the upload component looks like this, might have modified it some times trying to fix the error.

Upload-Component:

```
ImageUploader receiver = new ImageUploader();
upload = new Upload("", receiver);
upload.addSucceededListener(receiver);
addComponent(upload);
```

ImageUploader (as taken from [Book of Vaadin](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/components.upload.html)):

```
class ImageUploader implements Upload.Receiver, Upload.SucceededListener {

    public OutputStream receiveUpload(String filename, String mimeType) {
      // Create upload stream
      FileOutputStream fos = null; // Stream to write to
      File file = new File(filename);
      try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
      } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }

      ... database stuff ...

      // Return the output stream to write to, necessary for framework
      return fos;
    }

    public void uploadSucceeded(Upload.SucceededEvent event) {
       ... UI-Stuff ...
    }
  }
```

Using this on a localhost instance works all fine. But having it deployed to a server makes it return the following error immediately upon hitting the upload-button. However there is no UI-error-message shown.

```
[#|2015-03-17T15:42:14.153+0000|WARNING|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.container.web.com.sun.enterprise.web|_ThreadID=515;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|StandardWrapper$
java.io.IOException: The multipart stream ended unexpectedly
        at com.vaadin.server.communication.FileUploadHandler.readLine(FileUploadHandler.java:302)
        at com.vaadin.server.communication.FileUploadHandler.doHandleSimpleMultipartFileUpload(FileUploadHandler.java:360)
        at com.vaadin.server.communication.FileUploadHandler.handleRequest(FileUploadHandler.java:285)
        at com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1408)
        at com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:350)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:770)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1542)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:849)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:746)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1045)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:228)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
        at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
       at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
|#]
```

There is also a Vaadin [addon][3] that should make the process easier, but same results for localhost/server.

If it helps these technologies are used in the overall architecture:

- Maven 3.2.1
- Jenkins 1.602 (currently only used for build, not deploy)
- Hibernate (not relevant, as the error occurs before hibernate is used)
- MySQL (not relevant, as the error occurs before the database is accessed)
- JDK: 1.7
- IntelliJ Idea 14
- Glassfish 3.1.2

Used server hosts are Amazon AWS and DigitalOcean.

Right now I don't have anymore clue what could fix this error. Any recommendations? Any further details I can provide?

-- UPDATE on JVM version --

Regarding the JVM I noticed that locally I recently installed 1.8 on my local machine. Using a 1.7 JVM does not reproduce the error.

-- UPDATE on JVM patch level --

Using the same patch level (1.7.0_75) in the development environment does not reproduce the error.

Comment: any limits applied regarding the size of uploads? is your production environment reasonable close to your dev env?

Comment: I did not set any size limits, file-sizes did not exceed 500kb. The production is running on a linux server, whilst the local machine is windows. hardware resources on the server a smaller than on the local machine, but should not be the reason for the exception. will update that in the description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Upgrading to Glassfish 4.1 resolved the issue.** The upload- and database-process now runs smoothly. However I was not able to identify the reason behind this issue.

*Further information:*

- GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.1 (build 13)
- I was pointed to a Vaadin-[ticket](http://dev.vaadin.com/ticket/17108) that has the same issue, but the other way round: working with GF 4.1 but not with 3.1.
- I was not able to search for another glassfish ticket that has something to do with this issue. If someone knows one, please tell me where I can add further information.